# Where would a user ask a question for help with implementing math formulas in C#,C++,etc?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, math-se

I have tried to ask some questions on StackOverflow about implementation of mathematics into programming and received little to no help. i.e. Should be on Mathematics and other non-programming responses.

I have also tried to ask the same questions on Mathematics and they also cannot help. i.e. Should be asked on StackOverflow.

Is there somewhere where I can ask Applied Mathematical questions?

Comment: Link to some of the questions where you haven't received what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For pure math you should try the [Math Stackexchange site](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

For math as it applies to algorithms and programming, perhaps [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be the better place? Though it's not a site that I frequent, so I'm not wholly sure. Though it *seems* relevant there.

---

**Edited** in response to comment from OP:

> @David: I believe that StackOverflow would be more of a home for these types of questions, Programmers is a more professional type environment.

You could be right, having just looked over [area51 with a search of 'math'](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=math), it seems difficult to find a place where applied math would be particularly welcome. *However* the [faq of Math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq/) does offer the following advice:

> There are certain subjects that, while still being on-topic here, you can get better response on our sister sites:
>
> - Research-level mathematics — Math Overflow
> - Research level Algorithm design, complexity theory, etc — [Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq)
> - Algorithm implementation/design, computer simulation and modelling, etc — [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
> - Statistical analysis  —  [Statistical Analysis - Stack Exchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I believe that StackOverflow would be more of a home for these types of questions, Programmers is a more professional type environment.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not where is on topic. It could be on topic on either side. The problem you're facing is that there might not be too many mathematicians around these parts, or programmers around math.SE. SO is not a place that gather very specialized people (except, of course, people specialized in programming topics). I faced something similar with a chemical database question recently (the only answer I got was from an unregistered user that maintains a package similar to what I needed, so probably he runs routine google searches and found my question).

I do not know your field, but a quick google search for "computational mathematics forums" yielded these results. You might give them a try:

- [ComputationalMathematics.org Forums](http://www.computationalmathematics.org/forums/)
- [Math Forum - Computer Science](http://www.mymathforum.com/viewforum.php?f=44&sid=00e93f08aedc6b6b739c8ce48414566a)
- [scienceforums.net - Applied Mathematics](http://www.scienceforums.net/forum/16-applied-mathematics/)
- [Math Help Forum: Mathematics Software Discussion](http://www.mathhelpforum.com/math-help/f46/)